# Comparing characters always returns false

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am very new to PL/SQL, and I already have problem with my stored procedure. It compiles, but one IF statement never works as needed.

```
IF SUBSTR(p_phone_number, 5, 1) <> '2' OR SUBSTR(p_phone_number, 5, 1) <> '6' THEN
    RAISE ex_phone_number_non_lv_custom2;
END IF;
```

When calling procedure, `p_phone_number` is `'+37122222222'` with type of `VARCHAR2(12)`. I used server output for `SUBSTR(p_phone_number, 5, 1)` and it is 2 as expected, but this IF statement still raises my exception. Why is it happening?

Comment: This is simple Boolean logic. 2 != 6 so at least one branch of your OR statement must be false .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `and` . . . but better yet, use `not in`:

```
IF SUBSTR(p_phone_number, 5, 1) NOT IN ('2', '6') THEN
    RAISE ex_phone_number_non_lv_custom2;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using OR and you should use AND.

```
IF SUBSTR(p_phone_number, 5, 1) <> '2' AND SUBSTR(p_phone_number, 5, 1) <> '6' THEN
    RAISE ex_phone_number_non_lv_custom2;
```

With OR it will always throw an exception as one of the two conditions is always true.